# Github html preview from html file not working

Tags: github, github-pages

I Have seen several posts regarding this feature to preview HTML file on GitHub. Some suggest prepending https://htmlpreview.github.io/ before the real URL and some suggestions to create GitHub pages that I don't want to do now because then I have to re-create most of the thing on .yml

But my confusion is why this link showing HTML preview but not mine when I prepend the same string on my repo's HTML page. Please let me know If any other way I can see the HTML preview on github

**Working:**

https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/bartaz/impress.js/blob/master/index.html

**Not Working:**

https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/sany2k8/setuptools/blob/master/How_to_Install_Spark_on_Ubuntu.html

**Showing 404 Not Found**

> Error: Cannot load
> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sany2k8/setuptools/master/How_to_Create_Github_Pages.html:
> 404 Not Found

Answer (score 1):

**Check these steps:**

-Your repository is public.
(Settings>General>Danger Zone>Change repository visibility>Make public)
-The size of the files are not very large.
-The Repository link is in HTTPS and not in SSH.

[image: https]

**EDIT:**
I found [this question](https://github.com/htmlpreview/htmlpreview.github.com/issues/80) about the private repository and preview, if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

When your html file is excessively big then often github may fail to open the file. In such cases you can check the raw version of the HTML file.

Comment: Yes its big but not too much, what are the other ways fix that? I have tried with gh-pages feature branch but that also did not work